# Evaluating tricky definite complex integral and getting numerical result as a single complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, complex-integration, numerical-calculus, error-function

For given constants $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and I would like to numerically evaluate the following complex integral

$$\int_{-1}^{1} (1-|x|) \exp(ia(b+x)^2) \, d\mathrm{x}. $$

I am not good in complex integration at all but using Wolfram alpha I got these identities
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} x \exp(iax^2) \, d\mathrm{x} = 0,
$$

$$
\int_{-E}^{E} |x| \exp(iax^2) \, d\mathrm{x} = -\frac{i(-1+e^{iaE^2})}{a},
$$

$$
\int_{-E}^{E}  \exp(iax^2) \, d\mathrm{x} = -\frac{\sqrt[-4]{-1} \sqrt{\pi} \mathrm{erf}((-1)^{3/4} \sqrt{a} E)}{\sqrt{a}}
$$
and so
$$
\int_{-1}^{1} |x| \exp(iax^2) \, d\mathrm{x} = -\frac{i(-1+e^{ia})}{a},
$$

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}  \exp(iax^2) \, d\mathrm{x} = -\frac{\sqrt[-4]{-1} \sqrt{\pi} \mathrm{erf}((-1)^{3/4} \sqrt{a})}{\sqrt{a}}
$$

Using these and completing the square I can symbolically evaluate the original integral.

Now how about numerical evaluation. In `C++` there is `erf` function implemented in `cmath` header. But how to evaluate $\sqrt[-4]{-1}$ and $(-1)^{3/4}$? Does the integral has multiple solutions? And is there one solution, which is somehow more natural then others to use it as a result of numerical integration?

Comment: The first formula is useful. The second one is just the definition of the right hand side, as written, and I'm not sure if C++ has the implementation of erf for *complex* argument values (just check it first). If you use the definition of erf of a complex ardument, you'll get $\int_{-1}^1 e^{iax^2}dx=2\int_0^1 e^{-(-i)ax^2}dx=\frac{2}{\sqrt a}\int_0^\sqrt a e^{-(-i)x^2}dx=\frac{2e^{i\pi/4}}{\sqrt a}\int_0^{e^{-i\pi/4}\sqrt a}e^{-z^2}dz=\frac{e^{i\pi/4}\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt a}erf(e^{-i\pi/4}\sqrt a)$. I used $-i=(e^{-i\pi/4})^2$ here. WA prefers $-i=(e^{3 i\pi/4})^2$, but the result is the same.

Comment: If you cannot find the implementation of erf for complex numbers in the standard C++ libraries, here is the related discussion on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803487/imaginary-error-function-in-c